# How to put a UIView in a UITableView and It will be pinned on the bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to build a UITableView Controller, which will be my app's ABOUT information session.

At the bottom of the view, it will be reserved as circle menu. So I need a UIView with height of 200 there, when I drag a UIView to the controller, it always sit as a table cell. [image]

As you can see, the red area always sit under the last table cell group, how to pin it on the bottom of the View Controller.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My answer was same as the answer you have accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a `UIView` at the bottom of the `UITableViewController`. If that is a hard requirement you have to switch to `UIViewController`. And then you can use `UITableView` and other `UIView`'s as well.

If you are using a navigation controller with `UITableViewController` then you can use `UIToolBar` which sticks at the bottom of view controller but have some limitations too. See this

Answer (score 1):

Get UIView controller and put tableview instead of UITableViewController.  From side inspector drop UIView out of tqbleview.  And in inspector menu for UIView set auto resizing mask for UIView according.

Comment: I followed your advice, but the Xcode says, Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableView Controller instances.